# Не работает INSERT INTO (MySQL PHP Денвер)

Tags: php, mysql

Есть БД:

```
CREATE TABLE `tovar` ( 
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` VARCHAR(12),
`partRu` VARCHAR(100),
`partUk` VARCHAR(100),
`sectionRu` VARCHAR(100),
`sectionUk` VARCHAR(100),
`nameRu` VARCHAR(100),
`nameUk` VARCHAR(100),
`descriptRu` TEXT,   
`descriptUk` TEXT,   
`price` DECIMAL(9,2),
`dateCreate` DATE,
`number` MEDIUMINT,   
`unit` VARCHAR(15),
`pathImg` VARCHAR(255),
`madeIn` VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Для 4-х разных переменных INSERT в БД работает:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tovar` (id, code, partRu, partUk) VALUES (NULL, '$code', '$partRu', '$partUk')"; // РАБОТАЕТ-Запись в БД произведена!
$query = "INSERT INTO `tovar` (id, code, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES (NULL, '$code', '$nameRu', '$nameUk')"; // РАБОТАЕТ-Запись в БД произведена!
```

Для 6-ти переменных INSERT в БД НЕ работает:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `tovar` (id, code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES (NULL, '$code', '$partRu', '$partUk', '$nameRu', '$nameUk')";   // не РАБОТАЕТ
```

Ошибка записи в БД :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nameR', 'nameU')' at line 1

Пробовал и полную запись в БД для всех переменных сразу:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Никогда раньше (2 года) не сталкивался с таким фокусом.
Перепробовал кучу вариантов в разных таблицах - всё одно и то же.
Переменные - самые простые, присвоил перед записью, например `$nameRu = "nameR";`

Comment: Сделайте вывод переменной `$query` (для не работающего запроса) _после_ подстановки переменных и добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Ну так посмотрите перед запуском свою переменную – `var_dump($query); die();` Поскольку вы вставляете переменные без экранирования (что ОЧЕНЬ плохо), то ваш запрос может испортиться, о чем вам и говорит ошибка

Comment: возможно, внутри переменных попадаются кавычки. надо их «заэскейпить».

Comment: @alexander barakin

Comment: Сделал:
$query = "INSERT INTO `$TblDB` (code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES ('$code', '$partRu', '$partUk', '$nameRu', '$nameUk')"; 
var_dump($query);
Результат:
string(117) "INSERT INTO `tovar3` (code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES ('code', 'hhhRRR', 'hhhhhUUU', 'nameR', 'nameU')" Ошибка записи в БД : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nameR', 'nameU')' at line 1

Comment: @alexander barakin    Сделал:
$query = "INSERT INTO `$TblDB` (code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES ('$code', '$partRu', '$partUk', '$nameRu', '$nameUk')"; 
var_dump($query);
Результат:
string(117) "INSERT INTO `tovar3` (code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES ('code', 'hhhRRR', 'hhhhhUUU', 'nameR', 'nameU')" Ошибка записи в БД : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''nameR', 'nameU')' at line 1

Comment: @Леонид05-05 Странно, я скопировал приведенный вами тут запрос и получилось, что он 113 байт, а ваш var_dump дал 117 байт, откуда еще 4 символа, которые сюда не скопировались, либо вы их не разглядели на экране (т.к. это например управляющие символы, которые не видны)

Comment: Очень интересно! Но откуда они могут появиться??  Может где-то затесались русские буквы, а кодировка UTF8?? Буду проверять. Спасибо!!

Comment: Большое спасибо!!! На месте пробелов в запросе были какие-то невидимые знаки. Убрал, - всё заработало. В жизни с таким не встречался. Еще раз спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @Леонид05-05 можете оформить вашу последнюю находку в виде ответа на основной вопрос? Сейчас вы ведете диалог в комментариях

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO `tovar` (id, code, partRu, partUk, nameRu, nameUk) VALUES (NULL, '$code', '$partRu', '$partUk', '$nameRu', '$nameUk')";   // не РАБОТАЕТ

Comment: @Mike
Я, видимо, где-то скачал запрос (форму) $query = "INSERT INTO `tovar` (id, code, partRu, partUk,... В этой форме вместо знака пробела (который и виден как пробел) в каком-то месте стояла муть с длиной больше 1 байта.  Mike  обратил мое внимание на разницу в длине запроса. Методом удаления текста запроса дошел  до пробелов. Еще раз спасибо Mike и всем остальным.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте cделать запрос похожий на этот, и зачем вы пишите id ? у вас же AUTO_INCREMENT стоит он автоматически заполнить поле id

```
"INSERT INTO `$table` SET `ip`='".$ip."', `article`='".$likeds."'";
```

или так

```
"INSERT INTO `table` (`time_add`, `type`, `adv`, `user_id`, `username`, `text`) VALUES ('".TIME."', '".$type."', '".$id."', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$users_info['username']."', '".$text."')"
```

Comment: Делал по всякому. Результат - You have an error in your SQL syntax;...

Answer (score 0):

Не работал INSERT для вставки части полей. Причина была в отсутствии значений по умолчанию для всех полей